# No System Diagnostic Debug output for W3WP Process

Tags: logging, w3wp

I use Debug View to debug Powershell scripts that run in the W3wp process. I haven't been seeing any debug output for a while now. I suspect this is due to a Windows update. Does anyone have any ideas on how to re-enable logging?

I checked the settings in Debug-View and it's fine.